# Linq Select New List Property Null Check

Tags: c#, linq, null

I have a below LINQ query :

```
var productTypes = from ProductDto e in Product
                            select new 
                            {
                                Id = e.Product.ID, 
                                Name = e.Product.name 
                            };
```

In the above LINQ query the e.Product may be `null`.But I am not getting the way to find out.

Can anyone help me out ? I want to assign `null` in productTypes variable if e.Product is `null`.

Comment: You should ask to Sunil Agrawal sir or Ajay sir :-)

Comment: Use lamda expressin insted of linq query.

Comment: What do you mean "I want to assign null in productTypes variable if e.Product is null"?  Do you mean you want the "Id" field to be null if Product is null?  You'd have to make it a nullable int which may affect your result.

Answer (score 21):

you can check for **null** using [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) like this:

```
var productTypes = from ProductDto e in Product
                            select new 
                            {
                                Id = e.Product != null ? e.Product.ID : 0, 
                                Name = "xyz"
                            };
```

Comment: Ehsan please see the updated question.I want output like above.

Comment: This one should be marked as accepted answer since it show how to check null which he want to know. But the question should also not be down voted as his question can help other.

Answer (score 4):

I got the way.We can do it by using lambda expression :-

```
var productTypes = ProductList.Where(x => x.Product != null)
                              .Select(x => new 
                                          { 
                                            Id = x.Product.ID, 
                                            Name = x.Product.Name 
                                          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not interesting in nulls in your products at all, you can add `where` condition

```
var productTypes = from ProductDto e in Product
                        where e.Product.ID != null
                            select new 
                            {
                               Id = e.Product.ID, 
                               Name = e.Product.name 
                            };
```

In case you need your nulls, please use following:

```
var productTypes = Product.Select( prod => {
            if (prod.ID != null)
            {
                return new { ID = prod.ID, Name = prod.Name };
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
           } );
```